# MySQL InnoDB Index in swap

Tags: mysql, index, innodb

I can't find any info regarding my question. This is more theoretical question.
For example, i have table **keywords**.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords` (
  `kid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `custom_idx` (`language_id`,`keyword`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

My server has 1GB of free RAM memory. My table has millions of rows and size of my **custom_idx** is more than 1GB. *Index can't fit into RAM memory*. What would mysql do ? Is only part of this index will be stored in the memory ? Will this break BTREE/Clustered index performance dramatically ?

Also, if size of my index can't fit into **innodb_buffer_pool_size** limits, what would happen ?

Is replication is the answer to enormous InnoDB databases where indexes can't fit into RAM memory ?

I need to keep all my indexes in RAM ? What if my db size is more than 500gb?

Comment: I need the following information: 1) `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM keywords;` 2) `SELECT MAX(language_id) FROM keywords;`

Comment: Are you looking for something different than your [identically asked question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128903/mysql-innodb-index-in-swap) ?

Comment: yes, this answer wasn't exactly what i was looking for. 1) 631 2) 14. But my question is more theoretical than practical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InnoDB caches both data pages and index pages into the InnoDB Buffer Pool

MyISAM caches index pages only. In fact, you can do something interest if you combine replication with MyISAM.

## **SUGGESTION #1**

Since there only 6700 spoken languages on Earth, you should use SMALLINT for language_id instead of INT. Makes for a smaller table and smaller index.

## **SUGGESTION #2**

If you use MySQL Replication, try out this crazy idea: Convert the `keywords` table on the Slave to MyISAM. Leave the Master's Copy of the `keywords` as InnoDB.

You could run this query on the Slave ONLY to convert it...

```
ALTER TABLE keywords ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

## **SUGGESTION #3**

Once you make the `keywords` table MyISAM on the Slave, you could create a dedicated MyISAM Key Cache just for `keywords` as follows (Example: Setup 512M KeyCache for `keywords`):

First create a script on the Slave

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
echo "SET GLOBAL keywords_cache.key_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 *512;" > InitMySQL.sql
echo "CACHE INDEX keywords IN keywords_cache;" >> InitMySQL.sql
echo "LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE keywords;" >> InitMySQL.sql
```

Next, create the following entry for the startup script in /etc/my.cnf on the Slave

```
[mysqld]
init-file=/var/lib/mysql/InitMySQL.sql
```

Then, just restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

This keeps keyword index pages away from the general MyISAM Key Cache and in a dedicated cache.

## **SUGGESTION #4**

Perform your keyword lookups on the Slave

I hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 2):

Back to the question...

The buffer_pool and key_buffer are just caches.  That is, if your index is bigger than the cache, mysql will take care of reading/writing/purging/etc the BTree blocks as needed.

If your table were a terabyte, you could still use it with only 1GB of available RAM.  Sure, it would be slower -- maybe just a little slower (if the working set is small); maybe a lot slower (if you do a lot of random lookups).

InnoDB's buffer_pool uses 16KB blocks; MyISAM's key_buffer uses 1KB blocks.  (Not that this matters.)

In any performance question, we need to know the queries that are applied.

```
SELECT kid WHERE language_id = 123 AND keyword = 'abc'
```

will probably take a disk hit, since the index cannot be fully cached.  That is, your application may be limited to about 100 such queries per second.

I will express caution about one of Rolando's suggestion -- turning over 0.5GB to the key_buffer will starve the data caching, and may slow things down.