# Does mysqld wait for init-script code to complete before opening the instance?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I'm trying to automate the execution of an application code at *MySQL* startup. 
The [init-file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file) server option seems handy and I need to know if mysqld waits for all the code in the *init-file* to complete before making the instance and the databases available.

I tried to set up a quick test case that doesn't seem to work as I expect:

create a simple test table and a procedure that just inserts a record

```
create table init_test_tab (x char);
delimiter $$
drop procedure init_test $$
create procedure init_test(p char(1))
begin
  do sleep(300);
  insert into init_test_tab VALUES(p);
END
$$
```

call the procedure from an init-file:

```
$ cat /var/lib/mysql/mysql-init.sql
call xxxx.init_test('y');
$ grep init /etc/mysql/my.cnf
init-file = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-init.sql
```

Restart the server to verify the timings and check the content of the test table:

session 1 - the table is empty:

```
[Wed Nov 28 15:54:26 2012]> select * from init_test_tab;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

session 2 - restart mysqld:

```
# time service mysql restart
mysql stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 3031

real    0m10.116s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.068s
```

Note that it takes just 10s to restart.

session 1 - connection lost (as expected):

```
[Wed Nov 28 15:54:33 2012]> select * from init_test_tab;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
ERROR:
Can't connect to the server

[Wed Nov 28 15:54:45 2012]> select * from init_test_tab;
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    2
Current database: xxxxx

+------+
| x    |
+------+
| y    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

[Wed Nov 28 15:54:50 2012]>
```

Note that the procedure is invoked automatically (as expected) as the table is not empty anymore. But the insert should have been executed only after the sleep(300) call, not immediately (or, to be accurate, just in a few seconds).

So now I'm trying to understand:

1. If I put a procedure call (or whatever application code) in the init-file, will it be executed as expected (in my test case the sleep call seems to be skipped)?
2. Could I have some kind of logging of what gets executed (apart from modifying the code itself)?
3. If the code in the *init-file* takes time, could that affect the availability of the *MySQL* instance right after the restart?

Thanks
Dimitre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Trying to Understand #1

> If I put a procedure call (or whatever application code) in the init-file, will it be executed as expected (in my test case the sleep call seems to be skipped)?

Yes, it will. In the past, I have recommended using `init-file` to create dedicated keycaches for MyISAM tables:

- `Aug 28, 2012` : [MySQL InnoDB Index in swap](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/mysql-innodb-index-in-swap/23300#23300) (See Suggestion #3)
- `Mar 20, 2012` : [optimal table design mysql with primay key and varchar value](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15321/optimal-table-design-mysql-with-primay-key-and-varchar-value/15322#15322)

I am currently do this for clients at my employer's company.

## Trying to Understand #2

> Could I have some kind of logging of what gets executed (apart from modifying the code itself)?

Unfortunately, no. You would have one of the following:

1. Write changes to some MyISAM table to mark stages
2. Run something like `SELECT 'DEBUG#1;'` ... `SELECT 'DEBUG#2;'` to see if it echoes to the error file. Place these SELECT queries in different places within your code.

## Trying to Understand #3

> If the code in the init-file takes time, could that ? affect the availability of the MySQL instance right after the restart

Just from the example you posted in the question, they answer would still be no. However, in order for to be sure, you will have to let mysqld tell you this. Assuming `/var/log/mysqld.log` is your error log, here is how to check:

- Open an SSH seesion (Session1) to DB Server
- Open an SSH seesion (Session2) to DB Server
- In Session1, `service mysql stop`
- In Session1, `tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log`
- In Session2, `service mysql start`

Watch the output of Session1. If you see something like

```
121018 17:59:09 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

in under 5 minutes (300 seconds), this then confirms that the answer is no, the availability of the MySQL instance right after the restart is not affected.

## Why does SLEEP() not work ???

As to why the `SLEEP` function seems to be skipped, here is my best guess:

Way back in MySQL 5.0.12, [SLEEP was getting inserted into the query cache via some optimization](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12689). It could be possible that the Stored Procedure's internal code is being optimized and mysqld decided not to let `SLEEP` interfere with the formation of the EXPLAIN plan and its execution.

[The patch for it was applied when back in MySQL 5.0](http://lists.mysql.com/internals/28551). Could that patch have been missed when going from MySQL 5.0 to MySQL 5.1 and beyond? That's one possibility. Another possibility is that `SLEEP` is optimized away in spite of the patch.

Some use `SLEEP` to imbed mutexing, perform stress testing, or fancy job scheduling

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/4284524/491757
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/949950/491757
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,242758,242792#msg-242792
- http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/scheduling-procedure-execution-in.html

Using `SLEEP` does not always perform as expected.

## UPDATE 2012-11-27 15:50 EDT

If you really want to control the `SLEEP` function, DO NOT USE THE FUNCTION !!!

Create a loop that checks for the passing of time

Instead of your code

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure init_test $$
create procedure init_test(p char(1))
begin
  do sleep(300);
  insert into init_test_tab VALUES(p);
END
$$
```

imbed the loop like this:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure init_test $$
create procedure init_test(p char(1))
begin
  declare dt_now,dt_then datetime;
  declare x int;

  set dt_now = now();
  set dt_then = dt_now + interval 300 second;
  while dt_now < dt_then do
    set dt_now = now();
  end while;

  insert into init_test_tab VALUES(p);
END
$$
```

Please see if that construct work for you.

Comment: Hi @RolandoMySQLDBA, thanks for replying! Do you have an idea why the sleep call seems to be skipped in the test case I posted?

Comment: Unfortunately the output from the statements in the init-file don't appear in the error log.

Comment: Note that the sleep seems to be skipped only when invoking the procedure using the init-file. It works just fine When I invoke the procedure interactively (using the mysql cli).

Comment: As far as calling the `SLEEP`function goes, I would expect mysqld to handle certain operations differently when performing internal/intrinsic functionality such as 1) Triggers, 2) Slave Threading, 3) Event Scheduling. Calling `SLEEP` has no useful purpose. In fact, I have never seen `SLEEP` replicated to a Slave although `SLEEP` can be caught in a slow query log.

Comment: Rephrasing the question: why calling a procedure via init-script behaves differently compared to manual invocation?

Comment: Think about it: 1) you could impose a DDoS attack with a simple restart of mysql if a stored procedure call at init time could perform a real-time pause that never ends. 2) It would probably be possible to execute a stored procedure whose `SECURITY_TYPE` is `DEFINER`. 3) Potential GRANT issues could be circumvented during such execution becasue it is possible to redo user GRANTS at init time ( http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/recovering-a-mysql-root-password-the-fourth-solution ). Many check and balances are rather insecure for mysqld's internal init process.

Comment: Completely agreed, however I don't see how a procedure is different from a plain SQL - the code will be executed with the higher possible privileges anyway. And even if the procedural code would potentially present higher security risks, I would expect that fact to be documented. Anyway thank you for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: Thank you very much, Rolando! My test with your loop using now() + interval prove that mysqld actually waits for the code to complete before opening the instance! So, we need to be very careful when using the init-file parameter! Thanks again!